# How can I make the Application menu Show (Recent) Files?

Tags: gnome, files, gnome-shell, 19.04

I would like to search for files in the same way im opening applications (opening via the 'windows'-/ super-button).

Actually, there is already an entry that shows some files, listed in an extra menu called 'Files'.

But not all. I don't know which criteria files need to meet in order to show up there.